Is weighted Bessel space a Hilbert space?
I'm studying about weighted spaces. If $L_w^2(\mathbb{R}^n)=\left\{u\colon \left\|wu\right\|_{2}<\infty\right\}$, this space is a Hilbert space with the natural inner product $\langle u,v\rangle_{L_w^2}=\langle wu,wv\rangle_{L^2}$.
Now, if $H_w^{2}=\left\{u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\colon \left\|w J^{-s}(u)\right\|_{2}<\infty\right\}$ (weighted Bessel space) where $J^{-s}(u)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}((1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\widehat{u})$
Is $H_w^2$ a Hilbert space? Is the inner product $\langle u,v\rangle_{H_w^2}=\langle J^{-s}(u),J^{-s}(v)\rangle_{L_w^2}$?
Actualization:
My attempt:
The application $T:u\mapsto wJ^{-s}(u)$ is invertible with inverse $T^{-1}:u\mapsto J^{s}(u/w)$. Therefore, the inner product is
$\langle u,v\rangle_{H_w^{s,2}}=\langle T^{-1}(u),T^{-1}(v)\rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}$. This is right?

Did you try to check using the definition of scalar product and complete space ?

I was thinking of doing it by proving that space is isomorphic to $L^2$ but I don't know if it will be right.
